# Can't use an array for switch case

Tags: android, arrays, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have an array created in my strings file(in values folder).
Now i want to use it for choosing on spinner, using switch case.
something like that:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,workers);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

public void addUser(View view) {

            switch (Arrays.toString(workers)){

                case workers[0]:        //this option isn't compiling
                    Waiter waiter = new Waiter();

                    waiter.setName(editName.getText().toString());
                    waiter.setLast(editLast.getText().toString());
                    waiter.setPass(editPass.getText().toString());

                    name = editName.getText().toString();
                    last = editLast.getText().toString();
                    passId = Integer.parseInt(editPass.getText().toString());
               break;

               case workers[1]:
               break; 
}
```

and so on..

EDIT:

tried now with if statement, this method should add me new workers on button press, but after that when i press the button nothing happens:

```
public void addUser(View view) {

    if(Arrays.toString(workers).equals(workers[0])) {

        Waiter waiter = new Waiter();

        SQLiteDatabase usersDB = openOrCreateDatabase("USERES_DATABSE.sqlite", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        usersDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_table (name TEXT, last TEXT, pass INTEGER)");

        waiter.setName(editName.getText().toString());
        waiter.setLast(editLast.getText().toString());
        waiter.setPass(editPass.getText().toString());

        name = editName.getText().toString();
        last = editLast.getText().toString();
        passId = Integer.parseInt(editPass.getText().toString());


        if (editName.getText().toString().isEmpty() ||
                editLast.getText().toString().isEmpty() ||
                editPass.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {


            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserCreatingActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Oops,");
            alertDialog.setMessage("You forgot to fill something");
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();


        } else {

            usersDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO users_table VALUES('" + name + "','" + last + "','" + passId + "')");


            AlertDialog alertSucsess = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserCreatingActivity.this).create();
            alertSucsess.setTitle("Congrats,");
            alertSucsess.setMessage(name + " " + last + " Has been created");
            alertSucsess.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));

                }
            });

            alertSucsess.show();

        }

        usersDB.close();

//          ADDING SHIFT MANAGER

        } else if (Arrays.toString(workers).equals(workers[1])){
```

Comment: please add more explanation on workers array...how you are adding values to it? Are you using the same for your spinner? Also can you add your implementation of onItemSelected

Comment: @ShadowDroid i am using workers array for my spinner, this array is in my values folder in strings file, because it's written in Hebrew, i don't add values to it, it has the same values all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone mentioned you **cannot use arrays with the switch so you are going for the if**. And the way you have written condition seems incorrect `if(Arrays.toString(workers).equals(workers[0]))`. After going through question then based on the selection in the spinner you have to add user...correct me if I am wrong. So first you need to find the value of spinner.
**Solution1**
Create a instance String variable and implement onItemSelected as follows.

```
String workerSelected;

//your code
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            workerSelected=worker[position]

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

**OR**
Since you have added `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);` then just directly override method i.e following code is enough

```
 @Override
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
   workerSelected=worker[position]

  }
```

And then inside *addUser method* you can for if condition as

```
if(workerSelected.equals(worker[0])){
 //your code
}else if(workerSelected.equals(worker[1])){
 //your code
}
```

**Solution2**
Directly inside your *addUser method*

```
String workerSelected = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
if(workerSelected.equals(worker[0])){
     //your code
    }else if(workerSelected.equals(worker[1])){
     //your code
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use variables in a switch. Change to if.

Or you can change to case 0:, case 1:, case 2: since it's always workers[]

Comment: how can i change it to if? what should i write?

Answer (score 1):

`case` expressions must be constant values.

If possible values of `workers` are predefined, use these predefined and constant values as `case` expressions, instead.

Answer (score 1):

> A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in Numbers and Strings)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

You can't make the `case`s variables. The `switch` is fine as is. Just change the `case`s to constants.

If this is unworkable then you must do as Alex advises and resort to `if` statements, which in many *cases* result in fewer lines of code.

*For example*

```
        if (Arrays.toString(workers).equals(workers[0])) {
                Waiter waiter = new Waiter();

                waiter.setName(editName.getText().toString());
                waiter.setLast(editLast.getText().toString());
                waiter.setPass(editPass.getText().toString());

                name = editName.getText().toString();
                last = editLast.getText().toString();
                passId = Integer.parseInt(editPass.getText().toString());
           }
```

I think there is an error in your logic but can't be more specific without more code.

Comment: how can i write an array in if statement? @jonagon can you show me an example?

Comment: looks good i tried it, but for some reason it doesn't add my worker, i don't get the success alert. i add some code take a look maybe you can help.